# Determine who has opened an email in past year in a Marketing Cloud segment (data extension)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I have a population I want to send an email to, but only to those members who have opened an email in the past year. Measures seem to only look back 6-months, and don't seem to return accurate data when I've tried using them.

Is there any way to determine openers over a longer time frame? Can I query for this? This is such an easy function in every other ESP I've used. Not sure why I'm finding it so difficult in Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

The measures read dataviews, which are hard coded in the back end to 6 months. This is to reduce the performance overhead from running queries in a multi-tenanted environment.

You can raise a ticket for support to help you with this.

Alternative you can run queries daily and hive them off into a data extension to store these. This will not help you gain the past year, can but might be of use next year .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as painful as it is. It really feels like Marketing Cloud lags in functionality behind other ESPs. I really don't want to have to wait for support everytime I want anything that spans more than 6-months. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see and keep track of what happened more than 6 months ago, you will need to have some automation adding the tracking info in a DE. You will be able to query this DE.

You need to consider data retention policy, no PK, when you decide to insert the tracking data in it. For example only update it with tracking info from 2 month ago so it will not change and can be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to accomplish your use case:
1) In Email Studio, go to tracking--> Sends.
2) Search and open the email on which you want to check user engagement(those members who have opened an ***email*** in the past year).
3) On the Overview dashboard, in Inbox activity, click on 'Opens'.
4) You will see an entire list of users who have opened your email. Export that list and import it in a DE.
5) Use that DE to send your email.

Hope this helps.